# Maven property not resolved in parent tag

Tags: java, spring, maven

The following properties are not resolved:

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <spring.boot.version>1.3.3.RELEASE</spring.boot.version>
</properties>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

> Non-resolvable parent POM for com.myproject:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:${spring.boot.version}

Does anyone know what do I do wrong?

Comment: I noticed such an error when building with eclipse and maven(internal) version 3.3.x < 3.3.9. The error was gone for me after upgrading to maven 3.3.9

Comment: I do not know why, but if you remove spring.boot.version and just "hardcode" the version  in the parent-tag it'll work. If you let Spring Initializr create the pom file, the properties-tag comes after the parent-tag, so I'm not sure it is entirely correct to do it the other way around.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is normal. Currently, Maven does not evaluate properties inside the `<parent>` tag, so you need to write explicitely the version.

This was reported in [MNG-2569](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-2569) as a bug, which is duplicated by the more general [MNG-624](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-624). There are currently no plans to make this work in the future (the issue is closed as "Won't Fix").

Comment: It was surprisingly fixed in version 4.0.0, at least is what MNG-624 says.