# MAVEN: cannot use external argument at filed relativePath of parent section

Tags: maven

I am having a master maven pom (that build multiple project).
With my business, I need use 1 of 2 parent pom in different context. So I use argument at relativePath on parent section as below

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<modules>
    <module>../Client/com.hp.alm</module>
    <module>../Server/com.hp.alm</module>
    <module>../Server/com.hp.alm.helper</module>
    <module>../Server/com.hp.alm.model</module>
    <module>../Server/com.hp.alm.otaclient</module>
    <module>../Server/com.hp.alm.service</module>
</modules>
<parent>
    <groupId>com.hp</groupId>
    <artifactId>com.hp.parent</artifactId>
    <version>8.3.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath>${tabuild}\com.hp.parent\pom.xml</relativePath>
</parent>
```

But when I run build

```
mvn clean install -Dtabuild="..\parentBuild"
```

the error appears:

> [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs: 
>   Non-resolvable parent POM for
>   `com.hp:com.hpintegration.build:8.3.0-SNAPSHOT`:
>   Could not find artifact
>   `com.hp:com.hp.build.parent:pom:8.3.0-SNAPSHOT`
>   and '`parent.relativePath`' points at wrong local POM @ line 42, column
>   10  @

So, How I can use external argument at relative path in parent section?

Thanks,

David

Comment: Just a wild guess, can you try forward slash instead of backward in pom.xml?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Maven property not resolved in parent tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36111219/maven-property-not-resolved-in-parent-tag)

Comment: That's normal, Maven doesn't resolve property inside `<parent>`. You can refer to the linked answer.

Comment: Thank Tunaki. I think it's exactly the thing that I'm finding

Comment: HI Andrew. I tried but the result is not changed