# Maven - versioning parent pom and child pom to inherit parent pom version

Tags: maven, maven-3

I am using Maven 3.x and I have the below structure in my parent pom and child pom.

parent pom

```
<groupId>com.mygoogle.sample</groupId>
<artifactId>workorder</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<properties>
    <project.version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</project.version>             
</properties>
```

I have a child pom that is as below

```
<parent>
 <groupId>com.mygoogle.sample</groupId>
 <version>${project.version}</version>
 <artifactId>workorder</artifactId>     
</parent>
<artifactId>workorder-client</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
```

When I build my artifacts using mvn install, 
I see the jars getting built in my .m2 folder but the project.version is not replaced with the actual version , that is 1.0-SNAPSHOT.

1. Will the parent pom and/or child pom in my .m2 repository for each of the artifacts have the version specified or will it be project.version
2. Should I even specify project.version as a property in my parent pom. The maven documentation stated that project.version is available by defualt. I also tried mvn install post removing project.version property in my parent pom but the artifacts generated still had the version as {project.version} in my .m2 folder rather than the actual version
3. How do I set a version in my parent pom and have all my child pom have the same version. For eg, I want to set a version in workorder pom and workorder-client pom should also inherit the same version .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Maven property not resolved in parent tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36111219/maven-property-not-resolved-in-parent-tag)

Comment: You need to specify the `<version>` and can't rely on the `project.version` property: it is not evaluated in the `<parent>` element.

Comment: @Tunaki, Just edited my original post, I had intended to specify the actual version in parent pom but specified {project.version} property in the post which I have corrected now. So with the above setup, why is my child pom not picking up the property in the parent pom . Apologies for the initial confusion.

Comment: As answered in the linked question, you cannot have `<version>${project.version}</version>`. You must have `<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>` in the `<parent>` element.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You parent pom should be like:

```
<groupId>com.mygoogle.sample</groupId>
<artifactId>workorder</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
```

Your child pom should be like:

```
<parent>
   <groupId>com.mygoogle.sample</groupId>
   <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
   <artifactId>workorder</artifactId>     
</parent>

<artifactId>workorder-client</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
```

This will help in maintaining the versioning between the parent and child(s) smoothly.
Next time when you want to change the version, simply use the below command while pointing at the parent pom directory.

`mvn versions:set -DnewVersion=2.0-SNAPSHOT`

Comment: Can I have {project.version} in my child pom as below  <parent>
   <groupId>com.mygoogle.sample</groupId>
   <version>${project.version}</version>
   <artifactId>workorder</artifactId>     
</parent>

<artifactId>workorder-client</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

Comment: Just edited my original post, I had intended to specify the actual version in parent pom but specified {project.version} property in the post which I have corrected now. So with the above setup, why is my child pom not picking up the property in the parent pom

Comment: You cannot use `<version>${project.version}</version>` because, in the child pom, there is no such property defined. So the inheritance will not happen in the first place. Probably you are getting confused that it will inherit from the parent pom. But since `${project.version}` property is not defined, the child pom will not be able to resolve `<version>${project.version}</version>` value. Hence the inheritance will not take place.